# Closed regular languages

Tags: automata, regular-language

Are regular languages closed under the following construction?

$f(L) = \{w \mid w \in L$  and for all prefixes $x$ of $w$ it holds that $x \notin L$ $\}$

Comment: @Magdiragdag both formalisms are equivalent i think

Comment: @Magdiragdag i think it was. the implication excluding certain elements in $L$ only applies if $|w| > 1$, so $\epsilon \in L$ is neither eliminated nor introduced by $f$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag ok, so you regard $\epsilon$ as a prefix of any $w \ in L, |w| > 1$. i interpreted the op's phrasing meaning as 'non-empty prefix'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $f(L)$ is regular if $L$ is.

**Hint**. Take a deterministic finite automaton whose language is $L$ and remove all the outgoing transitions from the accepting states.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the alphabet, then $f(L) = L - LA^+$.